# How to define node module package in laravel5.5

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, node-modules, laravel-5.5

I'm new to Laravel. How can I access the packages in the `node_modules` folder in Laravel5.5?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. How exactly are you trying to "use" the node modules in your application? What did you already try? What did go wrong?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a guide that can help you ask good questions, so others can help you better.

Comment: Maybe it help.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is using [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) that supports several common CSS and JavaScript pre-processors.
[Click here to learn more on Laravel doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix)

Comment: I think the same thing has been given in a comment.